# yii2 joinWith related null

Tags: php, postgresql, activerecord, yii2

Report model:

```
public function getCampaign(): \yii\db\ActiveQuery
{
    return $this->hasOne(Campaign::class, ['cid' => 'cid']);
}
```

Campaign model:

```
public function getStream()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Stream::class, ['id' => 'stream_id']);
}
```

Stream model:

```
public function getTheme(): \yii\db\ActiveQuery
{
    return $this->hasOne(Theme::class, ['id' => 'theme_id']);
}
```

Report query:

```
$query = new Report();
$query = $query->find()->select($columns_array);
$query->joinWith('campaign.stream.theme t');
$query->groupBy('t.name');
```

Query result with ActiveDataProvide:

```
dd($dataProvider->getModels());
```

[image]

But if i check sql query in database, i got what i need

```
dd($query->prepare(\Yii::$app->db->queryBuilder)->createCommand()->rawSql);

SELECT "t"."name", 
sum(total_cost) AS "total_cost", 
sum(real_app_install) AS "real_app_install", 
sum(real_result_conversion) AS "real_result_conversion", 
sum(click) AS "click", 
sum(impression) AS "impression", 
sum(af_subs) AS "af_subs", 
sum(af_revenue) AS "af_revenue", 
avg(ctr) AS "ctr", 
avg(cpc) AS "cpc", 
avg(cpm) AS "cpm" 
FROM "reports" 
LEFT JOIN "campaigns" ON "reports"."cid" = "campaigns"."cid" 
LEFT JOIN "streams" ON "campaigns"."stream_id" = "streams"."id" 
LEFT JOIN "themes" "t" ON "streams"."theme_id" = "t"."id" 
GROUP BY "t"."name"
```

[image]

How can i get Theme`s name value with ActiveDataProvider ?

Comment: Try adding `cid` into list of selected fields. If the `cid` is not loaded framework cannot load related models because it doesn't know what rows to load.

Comment: After i added ``cid`` into list of selected fields i got the Campaign in relation. So then i added ``strean_id`` i got the theme.name

``$columns_array[] = 'max(reports.cid) as cid';
$columns_array[] = 'max(campaigns.stream_id) as stream_id';``